# Error trying to use ably Class "Ably\AblyRest" not found

Tags: php, laravel, ably-realtime

Ok so i been following the tutorial for ably [**Building a realtime chat app with Laravel using WebSockets**](https://ably.com/blog/building-a-realtime-chat-app-with-react-laravel-and-websockets)

but when i tried to create a messageEvent using the command:
`php artisan make:event PublicMessageEvent`

this is what it shows:  [Class "Ably\AblyRest" not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxiJw.png)

this is my composer.json required packeges package see if is anything wrong

```
  "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
```

I tried `composer-cache-clear` deleting the vendor folder and `composer install`, but nothing the same error

[The error appears even after clean composer install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGA5H.png)

now it even shows after installing all the packages so no idea what could it been.

Comment: You need to import the class `Ably\AblyRest` in your controller, and make sure you've already added it to your config files.

Comment: In PHP you can only make use of classes if they exist. You can make use of Composer to require your dependencies, including the library you ask about. For more information visit the libraries installation instructions: https://github.com/ably/ably-php#installation

Comment: The most important is to understand the tutorial. Some of the classes come from packages. The tutorial forgot to let you require the package: `ably/laravel-broadcaster`, now, if you understand what you need to do, keep going with your tutorial, otherwise learn about composer and then require the package and keep going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solved the problem, this tow comments help me to figure it out:

In PHP you can only make use of classes if they exist. You can make use of Composer to require your dependencies, including the library you ask about. For more information visit the libraries installation instructions: github.com/ably/ably-php#installation –
@hakre

The most important is to understand the tutorial. Some of the classes come from packages. The tutorial forgot to let you require the package: ably/laravel-broadcaster, now, if you understand what you need to do, keep going with your tutorial, otherwise learn about composer and then require the package and keep going. –
@UnderDog

Also i want to thank @Ibrahim Hammed for answreing in teh tutorial there is a link to setup ably/laravel-broadcaster

and i didn't see the command `composer require ably/laravel-broadcaster`

so thanks you all so much.